# AppLovin SDK reports internal error. Code = -1. IOS

Tags: ios, ads, applovin

I'm doing everything as in the instructions. 
But when I do

```
 [ALInterstitialAd shared].adDisplayDelegate = self;
 [ALInterstitialAd shared].adLoadDelegate = self;
 [ALInterstitialAd showOver:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

I receive code = -1 in

```
 -(void)adService:(ALAdService *)adService didFailToLoadAdWithError:(int)code
```

AppLovin SDK reports internal error.

In applovin site all ads is ON, and bundle id the same.

What could it be? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connect with AppLovin manager and they told me that because my country is not supported

Answer (score 0):

I released my game with "AppLovin SDK reports internal error" and now it's work correctly. I asked Applovin support and they told me it may be because there is no Ad for user to show at this time.